# Regex to match anything between braces except when quoted

Tags: javascript, regex

Does anyone know the best approach with regex to find anything in a string between braces, except when quoted. Example:

This is my `{string between braces}` which the pattern should match, but this `"{string between braces}"` should be ignored.

This regex will get me anything between braces...

```
/\{([^}]+)\}/g
```

**Edit:**

For those who have provided potential solutions so far, i thank you. To those who have questioned the ambiguity of this, apologies, it was quickly fired off with the intention of coming back to edit.

Given the following scenarios:

```
var str1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor {sit} amet, consectetur {adipiscing} elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua';
```

**Expect Result: {sit} and {adipiscing} be matched**

```
var str2 = 'Lorem "ipsum "dolor {sit} amet", consectetur" {adipiscing} elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua';
```

**Expected Result:  {sit} and {adipiscing} be matched (since neither are between open quotes)**

```
var str3 = 'Lorem ipsum "dolor {sit} amet", consectetur {adipiscing} elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua';
```

**Expected Result: {adipiscing}**

For the purpose of clarity, in terms quotes, we are talking quotes only, not apostrophes.

Comment: Because several details are not completely clear, and people interpret it differently, i'll ask: 1) in 'start"nonempty{str}nonempty"end', should '{str}' be matched? (If not, then here is a worse example: 'start""nonempty{str}nonempty""end') 2) in 'start"{str1}"{str2}"end', should anything be matched? Can one quote count for both braces?

Comment: Another detail: I so far assume, that in 'start""{str}""end', nothing should be matched. However, reading answers, another interpretation would be, that the quotes around {str} are already matched, and therefore don't 'span across' {str}. Which one is it?

Comment: @ASDFGerte you are correct, I fired this question of quickly and forgot to revisit so there is plenty of ambiguity. I will revisit later with use cases which will clarify. In terms of your 1st point, I would not expect {str} to be matched, in the worst example you give, it would be matched on the basis that although it is technically between quotes, it isnt between open quotes. The same applies for the additional detail . For the purpose of clarity I am referring to quotes, not apostrophes.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to match all the strings that start with `"{...}"` and capture the alternative using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in a group

```
"{[^{}]*}"|\{([^}]+)\}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BTA5IZ/1)

```js
const regex = /"{[^{}]*}"|\{([^}]+)\}/g;
const str = `{string between braces}
"{string between braces 2}"
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  if (m[1]) {
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
}
```

Another option is to also match either a `"` at the start or either a `"` at the end to not capture the group when having a single double quote.

```
"{[^{}]+}"?|{[^{}]+}"|{([^{}]+)}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kfXyiC/1)

In parts

- `"{[^{}]+}"?` Match from opening `"{` till closing `}` and optional `"`
- `|` Or
- `{[^{}]+}"` Match from opening `{` till closing `}` and `"`
- `|` Or
- `{` Match opening `{`
- `([^{}]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any char except `{` or `}`
- `}` Match closing `}`

```js
const regex = /"{[^{}]+}"?|{[^{}]+}"|{([^{}]+)}/g;
const strings = [
  '{string between braces}',
  '"{string between braces 2}"',
  '"{string between braces 3}',
  '{string between braces 4}"',
  'start"{str5}"{str6}"end'
].forEach(s => {
  let m;

  while ((m = regex.exec(s)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    if (m[1]) {
      console.log(m[1]);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: From OP's question, this situation is unclear, but a problem nontheless: 'start"{str1}"{str2}"end'

Comment: @ASDFGerte I have added another pattern to also match when only a single quote instead of capturing.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

```
{([^}]*)}(?!")
```

might be close.

```js
const regex = /{([^}]*)}(?!")/gm;
const str = `This is my {string between braces} which the pattern should match, but this "{string between braces}" should be ignored`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    

    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uHF97F/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/uHF97F/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions: 
[image]

---

We can possibly look at some other boundaries too:

```
(?:\s|^){([^}]*)}(?:\s|$)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oqqGXr/1/)

Comment: Hi Emma, I think `(?!"){` is redundant as `{` can not be equal to `"`

Comment: the `(?!")` at the beginning is useless, as by regex, it has to be followed by `{` anyways. Then, only the last part is relevant, making issues for unmatched quotes: 'test{mytext}"{othertext}"ddd', or even just 'test{mytext}"ddd'

Answer (score 2):

I would just match the part with the quotes first, and keep the part in the braces in a capture group.

```
"[^"]*"|\{([^}]*)\}
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/qu1CNH/1)

```js
const re = /"[^"]*"|\{([^}]*)\}/g;
const str = `there is a {braced part}
that's a "quoted {braced part}"`;
let match;

while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (match.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    if (match[1]) {
        console.log(match[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear situation e.g. for 'start""nonempty{str}nonempty""end'. You seem to be taking the interpretation of 'quotes dont have to be directly next to the curly braces' (in 'start"nonempty{str}nonempty"end' there would be no match), but then in the before mentioned string, it suddenly does count, although somewhat enclosed by quotes.

Comment: @ASDFGerte yup, that's the assumption that I made, considering what's more common in my mind. For instance, in the first string, the braces are either: not strictly between pairs of quotes (the pairs that are present are empty), or between escaped quotes (that's a legit syntax in C# for example, but not something one would see in an actual text that people come across often). In the second one, the braces are indeed between a pair of quotes (even if there are other strings along with it), so that's something I imagine the OP would not want to match.

Comment: Well, imho, the question is missing details. From the text as-is, i'd expect there should be no match for e.g. 'start"nonempty"{str}"nonempty"end' (it's the pattern "{str}", when looking only locally). However, your interpretation is also somewhat valid i guess.